# How to transfer data from bluetooth device to iPhone using bluetoothmanager.framework

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I'm working on an app that needs to connect to a none-BLE bluetooth Pulse Oximeter device to download its data.  This app will not be submitted to the app store so, at this stage, I'm not worried about it being rejected.

This is some basic code I've come up with, which is based on the [BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee) example, to connect to the pulse oximeter.

```
#import "MDBluetoothManager.h"
#import "BTMViewController.h"

@interface BTMViewController () <MDBluetoothObserverProtocol>
{
    IBOutlet UILabel * statusLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MDBluetoothDevice * connectedBluetoothDevice;

- (void)receivedBluetoothNotification:(MDBluetoothNotification)bluetoothNotification;

@end

@implementation BTMViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] registerObserver:self];

    if (![[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] bluetoothIsPowered])
    {
        //NSLog(@"Bluetooth not powered on!");
        [[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] turnBluetoothOn];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    statusLabel.text = @"Scanning ...";

    [[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] startScan];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] endScan];

    [self.connectedBluetoothDevice disconnect];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Bluetooth Connectivity

- (void)receivedBluetoothNotification:(MDBluetoothNotification)bluetoothNotification
{
    BOOL isPowered = [[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] bluetoothIsPowered];

    switch (bluetoothNotification)
    {
        case MDBluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification:
        {
            //NSLog(@"Bluetooth availability changed to %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:isPowered]);

            if (isPowered)
            {
                [[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] startScan];
            }

            break;
        }
        case MDBluetoothPowerChangedNotification:
            //NSLog(@"Bluetooth power changed to %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:isPowered]);
            break;
        case MDBluetoothDeviceDiscoveredNotification:
        {
            //NSLog(@"Bluetooth device discovered");

            NSArray* detectedBluetoothDevices = [[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] discoveredBluetoothDevices];

            for (int index=0; index<detectedBluetoothDevices.count; index++)
            {
                self.connectedBluetoothDevice = [detectedBluetoothDevices objectAtIndex:index];

                //NSLog(@"Bluetooth Device: %@ (%@)", bluetoothDevice.name, bluetoothDevice.address);

                if ([self.connectedBluetoothDevice.name isEqualToString:@"SpO2"])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Pairing with Pulse Oximeter");
                    [statusLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"Pairing with Pulse Oximeter" waitUntilDone:NO];
                    self.connectedBluetoothDevice.pin = @"7762";
                    [self.connectedBluetoothDevice connect];
                    [[MDBluetoothManager sharedInstance] endScan];
                }
            }

            break;
        }
        case MDBluetoothDeviceConnectSuccessNotification:
        {
            NSLog(@"Connected to Pulse Oximeter!");
            statusLabel.text = @"Connected to Pulse Oximeter!";
        }
            break;
        case MDBluetoothDeviceRemovedNotification:
            //NSLog(@"Bluetooth device removed");
            break;
        default:
            //NSLog(@"Unknown Bluetooth notification!");
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Does anyone know how to initiate a data transfer to download all the data using the private API?

or

Does anyone have an alternative way of connecting to a none-BLE device to download its data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For transferring data via a [Serial Port Profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/SPP.aspx) Apple requires an authentication which is handled by [MFi](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) certificates. I doubt this can be done easily.

But any contribution to this open topic is welcome!